# How many elements of order $5$ inside $ \mathbb{Z_{1000}}.$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

How many elements of order $5$ inside $\mathbb{Z_{1000}}.$

Need make multiplication table of some small values as for some elements $g\in G =\mathbb{Z_{1000}}$ has $g^{5}=1.$

Cannot find even one such number by means of multiplication table.

Comment: Hint: The element $200$ has order $5$.

Comment: You mention a multiplication table, but the addition operation may be what is meant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a proposition that says that if $G$ is a cyclic group of order $n$, given $d$ a divisor of $n$ then the number of elements of order $d$ is exactly $\phi(d)$. So in our case we have $\phi(5)=4$ elements of order $5$.

The proof of the proposition follows from that for every cyclic group and for every divisor of its order, there exists an unique subgroup of that order. That combined with the fact that for every cyclic group $H$ the number of elements of the group such as $H=\langle x\rangle $ is $\phi({\rm ord}(H))$

**EDIT**: To list the elements just solve the congruency
$$5x\equiv 0\pmod{1000}$$
for $0\leq x<1000$, which gives us the numbers on the form $200n$ for $n\in\mathbb{Z}$. So we have that the wanted elements are $200, 400, 600, 800$

Comment: Please tell the name of it. Also, can the four elements be listed?

Comment: You can find the proposition in the book <<J.M. Gamboa, Estructuras Algebraicas: Teoria Elemental de Grupos>>. To find the elements just find the subgroup of order $5$ of the group, that must be isomoprhic to $\mathbb{Z}_5$

Comment: @jiten There is a unique subgroup of order $5$ (For a cyclic group of order $n$, for each divisor $d$ of $n$, there exists a unique subgroup of order $d$) . So as long as you find just one element of order $5$, you know that it will generate the subgroup and you will find all $4$ from it. Now what is $\frac{1000}{5}$ ?

Comment: I think it's better to suggest an English textbook as not all users will be familiar with Spanish. To that extent you can have a look at [Joseph .A .Gallian Abstract Algebra](https://ict.iitk.ac.in/wp-content/uploads/CS203-Mathematics-for-Computer-Science-III-Gallian.pdf) (in the chapter of cyclic groups) .

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron $200$ generates: $400, 600, 800, 1000\equiv 0\pmod {1000}.$ $\langle 400\rangle = \{400, 800, 200, 600, 0\}.$ $\langle 600\rangle = \{600, 200, 800, 400, 0\}.$ $\langle 800\rangle = \{800, 600, 400, 200, 0\}.$

Comment: @jiten Exactly. And since there is only one subgroup of order $5$, by uniqueness, these $4$ have to be all the order $5$ elements.